# Tracking instances with generics and supporting subclasses

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I've defined the following generic class

```
public class ManagedClass<T> where T : ManagedClass<T>
{
    static ManagedClass()
    {
        Manager = new ObjectManager<T>();
    }
    public static ObjectManager<T> Manager { get; protected set; }

    public ManagedClass()
    {
        Manager.Add( (T)this );
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can use it like so:

```
class Product : ManagedClass<Product> {}
```

Now I can do something to the 7th product created like so:

```
Product.Manager.GetById(7).DoSomething();
```

The problem comes in if i try to use a derived class:

```
class ExtendedProduct : Product {}
```

now ExtendedProduct.Manager has a list of 'Products', and if i want to use a new function that I have added to ExtendedProduct (DoSomethingElse), I have to cast the object I get back like so:

```
((ExtendedProduct)ExtendedProduct.Manager.GetById(7)).DoSomethingElse();
```

This is a bit ugly, and the whole point of using generics for this is to avoid casting.  I suppose I could add a static constructor to the derived class to set Manager = new ObjectManager() and add a new Manager.addObject( this ) in the derived class constructor, but It seems like there should be some better way of doing this using generics.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ExtendedProduct.Manager` is the same thing as `Product.Manager`; the manager object can't act differently depending on where it's accessed from.

A couple of possibilities I can think of:

1. Hide the typecast inside the `GetById` method by making it generic: 
   `Product.Manager.GetById<ExtendedProduct>(7).DoSomethingElse();`
2. Use one `ObjectManager` instance per subclass, connecting them privately if needed

Option 1 reminds me of NHibernate's `ICriteria` interface. It's effectively the same as a typecast, but a little harder to accidentally break.

Answer (score 1):

Really what you're running into is a weakness with Generics.  Once your class has resolved what type it's using for generics, you're somewhat restricted in what you can do.

Normally, I'd say Dependency Injection would be a savior here, but since the problematic method is `static`, that muddies up the waters.

I'd say the best thing is to have the ObjectManager class do the work for you:

```
static public class ObjectManager<T>
{
    ... the code that already exists in ObjectManager ...

    static public U GetById<U>(long id)
    {
        object obj = GetById(id);
        if (obj is U)
            return (U)obj;
        return default(U);
    }
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
ExtendedProduct.Manager.GetById<ExtendedProduct>(7).DoSomethingElse();
```

It's not really tons more elegant than casting, but may be one of the only solutions using Generics.